# Trouble with Access Double Click Macro

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am making a database and am having an issue double clicking on a field in a subform and having it open up to the corresponding record. When I double click I am brought to the form I am looking for but not the record that corresponds with what I clicked. I am on my phone because our browsers at work are out of date so I am unable to paste my code.

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: Yeah I saw a bunch of posts like this one where people were able to double click a specific field in a subform and it would open up to the corresponding record in a main form. When I double click it just opens up to the first record regardless of whether I pick the first, second, third and so on

Comment: I have a where condition already and it still brings me to the first record.

Comment: I tell it to go the patientID that matches the patientID being clicked on but no luck

Comment: My condition is "CriteriaForm.[PatientID] =" & [PatientID] if that helps

Comment: yes, that is the name of the form I am attempting to open

Comment: It is an autonumber. When I tried it with a different field the result was the same as I initially reported

Comment: Oh, and the form is based off the results of a query if that makes any difference.

Comment: It does include patientID in the record source

Comment: It asks me to enter a parameter value and when I enter even a valid ID it still only goes to the very first record